# В каком слое должен происходить парсинг Json в Java модель?

Tags: java, android

Использую(на сколько себе ее представляю) Mvp и чистую арх.Загвоздка в следующем, в `data` слое  есть репозиторий который получает  `http_clenta`(`retrofit`) и идёт в сеть получает данные  в формате `JSON`

я в репозитории делаю сперва парсинг данных из `jsona` в  `pojo` а потом и конвертирую этот `pojo` под нужную мне модель для `domain` слоя
Код выгледит так

```
 @Override
    public Observable<AuthorizationModel> sendMail(String mail) {
        return httpClient.getHttpClient().create(AuthorizationServiceApi.class)
                .sendMail(UniqueUtils.getMacAddr(), mail)
                .flatMap(authrozationParser::parseAuthorizationDate)
                .flatMap(serverResponseMapper::transofrmToAuthorizationModel)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
    }
```

где нужно делать парсинг ? я делаю в репозитории.Но чую ой не правильно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***DataLayer*** Архитектура его мб разной. Могу посоветовать не волноваться, по таким вопросам, пока действительно станет неудобно использовать Репозитории. Ваш пример нормальный, а если вас волнует как отделить парсер, могу посоветовать разделять data, ведь парсить можно локальные данные (raw, files), удаленные данные, системные и тд. Те в вашем случае `authrozationParser` мог быть remoteData тогда у Репозитория может быть доступ к Remote и выглядило бы это примерно так:

```
.flatMap(remoteData::parseAuthorizationDate)
```

ваш репозиторий тогда облегчиться и ему будет проще выполнять предназначенную роль DataMapper, а из репозиториев уедет копипаста

Comment: благодарю!)нашео ответ на интересующие меня  вопосы